# Error in pnbd.LL(params, x, t.x, T.cal) : T.cal must be numeric and may not contain negative numbers in BTYD in r

Tags: r, model, statistics

I am building a pareto/nbd model using `BTYD` package and I am getting error while using it.
I have been following the directions from [BTYD walkthrough][1]. Everything was working fine until I got to the calibration customer-by-sufficient-statistic matrix (cal.cbs). I used the following code to generate cal.cbs, as instructed in the tutorial:

```
library(BTYD)
tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog)
cal.cbt <- dc.MergeCustomers(tot.cbt, freq.cbt)

birth.periods <- split.data$cust.data$birth.per
last.dates <- split.data$cust.data$last.date
cal.cbs.dates <- data.frame(birth.periods, last.dates,
                            end.of.cal.period)
cal.cbs <- dc.BuildCBSFromCBTAndDates(cal.cbt, cal.cbs.dates,
                                      per="month")
```

But I got a warning message:

```
In cbind(f, r, T) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

Though I overcome the warning by using the following code:

```
tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog.cal)
# instead of
tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog)
```

But I am getting error message while estimating parameters:

```
params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(cal.cbs)
```

> Error in pnbd.LL(params, x, t.x, T.cal) : 
>             T.cal must be numeric and may not contain negative numbers.

I have no clue how to fix this problem and why am I getting this error. Can anybody help me please? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure cal.cbs is a matrix, I had similar problem and this fixed it.

```
cal.cbs <- as.matrix(cal.cbs)
```